# Avoid multiple parent traversing iterations in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

I am trying to access great grand parent of currently selected tab.

I know it can be done with `$(tabSelected).parent().parent().parent()...` and so on.

But how to avoid that kind of multiple and repetitive parent traversing iteration and get the great grand parent in one go ?

Need a generalised function/selector for this.

Comment: Add HTML and complete JS code with the element you want to select by using `parent`

Comment: Use `closest`, `$(tabSelected).closest(mySelectorHere)`